# Why can't I create an EntityManager using JPA in my project?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, pom.xml

I hope you are well, I am trying to create a simple project to learn Java and its standards. I have the following config file for persistence

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="reuniones" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reunion" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdcb.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="(mypassword)" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I also have a small table of 3 fields called "reunion" (meeting) which has an id primary key (AUTO INCREMENT), a field called date with the type DATETIME and a varchar called subject. I emphasize that the database engine I am using is MySQL and the table is called "reunion".

[image]

For this table I have created the following class in Java with JPA annotations:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "reunion")
public class Reunion {
    
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Date fecha;

    @Column(name = "id")
    private String asunto;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getAsunto() {
        return asunto;
    }

    public void setAsunto(String asunto) {
        this.asunto = asunto;
    }

}
```

I have created an interface because I will be working with more entities later and I will need an interface that allows me to reuse some generic methods.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface Dao<T> {

    Optional<T> get(long id);

    List<T> getAll();

    void save(T t);

    void update(T t);

    void delete(T t);
}
```

And I have created an EntityManager:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class EntityManagerUtil {

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("reuniones");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        return manager;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManager manager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
        System.out.print("EntityManage class ===> " + manager.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

So far I think it's going very well, the problem is that in the EntityManager I have made a main method to test the creation of the EntityManager but when running as a Java application it throws me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that has occurred here is in the pom.xml file. This file has the dependencies and I am using the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-agroal</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Which I must add a property called type with the value of pom so that it does the correct reading.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-agroal</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Another solution is to use the hibernate core in the dependencies, which would be replacing the hibernate dependency that we have with the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This solves the problem and the application runs as normal.